# How to reach and check if docker engine is running in wsl2 from windows

Tags: docker, wsl-2, health-check

Docker engine (not docker-desktop) is installed in wsl2 and listening to port 2375. I want to make sure it is running from outside, i.e. windows and the status of engine is healthy.

Is there any rest endpoint to check whether the docker is healthy or not. e.g. http://ip-of-wsl2:2375 returns:

```
{"message":"page not found"}
```

Comment: Not really related to your question, but why are you running docker inside your `wsl2` when you can just access your windows-instance of docker from inside `wsl2` already?

Comment: I want to connect docker engine running inside wsl2 with docker UI extention of vscode as docker-desktop is no longer free.

Comment: It is free, as long as you are `Small companies (fewer than 250 employees AND less than $10 million in annual revenue)`. If you are not and your company doesn't want to pay for a $5/month subscription for you I would look for a different company. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the /info endpoint, i.e. `http://ip-of-wsl2:2375/info`. The response has a `SystemStatus` field that you can check.

More info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#33-misc

Comment: Thx, /info returns SystemStatus which means the docker engine is reachable. But the docker ui extension of vscode does not reach it. Any Idea?

Comment: No, sorry. You should create a new VS Code related question for that, I think

Comment: In case someone needs: ```http://ip-of-wsl2:2375/_ping``` will returns ```OK``` if docker engine is up and running

Comment: I saw the `_ping` endpoint. The SystemStatus field on /info seemed more explicit about the health. Sometimes 'ping' means 'reachable' and not necessarily healthy.